# Fast search query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Ok so I have a very big table and I need to search a url which have a keyword in it, and I am trying to do it with `LIKE` but `LIKE` is working just like this `'foo%'` and this checks if the string starts with `foo` and what I try to get is `'%foo%'`.

```
$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE url LIKE 'foo%' LIMIT number");
```

If you can give me an idea it would be perfect. Thanks!

Also I have an index for url and id.

Comment: `like '%...%'` is NEVER going to be fast. The DB cannot uses indexes on that sort of query, so it's forced to do a complete table scan every single time. What exactly is wrong with the query, other than being slow? `%foo%` is what you'd HAVE to use to find `foo` anywhere in that field. `foo%` will only find foo if it's the first 3 chars of the field's value.

Comment: I know that's why I asked this question, I don't know how can I search my table to find the keywords in the url fast...

Comment: you either use `like` as you are, or you can try messing with fulltext search, but I doubt it'll help much in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Using LIKE will slow the query down; one idea would be to try `LOCATE` instead:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOCATE('foo', url) > 0 LIMIT number");
```

`LOCATE` will simply find the index of the match else return 0, similar to `strpos()` in PHP (except strpos() will return false if no match). There is no wildcard matching.

Comment: I tried that and it is working but it is still slow, it took me like 10 seconds to get the resullts and I want something like 2-3 secs..

Comment: How long did the query using LIKE take?

Comment: How big is the table?

Comment: Ok so now the table is 100k rows but it will be way much bigger and the query took like 10-11 secs.

Comment: Oops I wanted to say that the LOCATE query took 10-11 secs the LIKE 'foo%' it's almost instant.